# Media query doesn't apply on footer section when viewed from a mobile phone but works when resize the browsers screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

The issue I have is, the footer section when viewed from desktop is very responsive and when i change the view port size
to mobile and tablet, it's still responsive. But when I open the app from my mobile phone, the footer looks unstyled.

This is how it looks from desktop 360px. Very responsive
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brfmO.png)

but from my mobile phone, it looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPZcA.png)

Here's live site's link : https://aginamena.github.io/Designo-Multi-Page-Website-/#/
Here's github repo : https://github.com/aginamena/Designo-Multi-Page-Website-

Comment: Please could you put enough code into your question to show the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a [mre] in the question post instead of linking us to an external page, because it will be hard for us to dig through the whole code to find the issue. Id also recommend new users to take the [tour] and visit the [ask] page for more information on asking a good question in Stack Overflow. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0):

This is not a media-query issue but the css property - `position: absolute` in the footer container is messing up the alignment in the Safari browser. I see your issue in [Desktop Safari responsive design mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzQpg.jpg) and iPhone device Safari browser. Desktop Chrome and Android device Chrome browser loads the footer fine.

I would suggest creating a footer container with the `position: relative` and another div with flex without using any absolute positioning. Then adjust the margin as you want it.